# Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined when using auth.user().onCreate

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I get this error when I register a new account. The code I use:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.afterRegFunction = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    var randInt = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1);
    var userObject = {
        u_n : user.uid, // user nickname
        u_n_c : admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, // next date to change nick
        u_a : randInt.toString(), // user avatar
        u_a_c : admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, // next date to change avatar
        d : admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, // date the account was created
        u_p : 0 // user points
    };
    admin.database().ref('userInfo/' + user.uid).set(userObject);
    admin.database().ref('nicknames/' + user.uid).set(user.uid);
});
```

I'm getting Function finished with status: 'error' in the logs and there isn't anything added in the database.

Comment: Boy, uhh... well that's a head scratcher for sure. You're doing it exactly like [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) suggests. I'd assume if you threw in a `console.log(user);` as the first line of the function, before the `var randInt` line, it would just print out `null` too, but sometimes weird things happen... I'd also try out a `console.log(typeof user);` and see if that tells us anything either.

Comment: What version of the firebase-functions package are you using? I notice you're using an old package's way of initializing the app.... `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` was changed to be just `admin.initializeApp();`... assuming you're on version 1.0 or later, try updating your code to initialize the SDK with the newer `admin.initializeApp();` instead

Comment: "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring the promises returned by set(), which is asynchronous.  With Cloud Functions background type functions, you're obliged to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  Since you have two items of work, you're going to need a new promise that resolves when both of them are resolved.

First of all, you should read the documentation on terminating functions, and [watch the video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) on how to deal with promises in Cloud Functions so you understand what you need to do.

Then, you'll realize you need to do the following:

```
const p1 = admin.database().ref('userInfo/' + user.uid).set(userObject);
const p2 = admin.database().ref('nicknames/' + user.uid).set(user.uid);
return Promise.all([p1, p2]);
```

Also with Cloud Functions, you're supposed to initialize the Admin SDK like this with no arguments:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

The way you're doing it now is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the link!